# SQLAlchemy OperationalError appears depending upon syntax

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am running a small Flask application and recently added SQLAlchemy as the ORM. We have been having issues with the application throwing 500 errors after being idle for some length of time. Once the error occurs, the query repeatedly fails until the application is restarted.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

The strange thing is this only happens if we query the database using the following syntax:

```
Logo.query.filter(Logo.default).first()
```

After re-writing the query like this:

```
stmt = db.session.query(Logo).filter(Logo.default)
logo = db.session.execute(stmt).first()
```

The error has disappeared. However, we prefer to use the former syntax as it is cleaner, and are still experiencing these errors in other spots of the code where the former syntax was used. We have already tried adding

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {"pool_pre_ping": True}
```

but it did not help. Any insight as to why this is occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Flask-SQLAlchemy?
It's interesting that changing the query syntax resolved the issue. This might be due to differences in how the SQLAlchemy session manages and utilizes connections in these two approaches. The Model.query approach, being a Flask-SQLAlchemy shortcut, might be handling the session or the connection differently compared to the explicit session.query() or session.execute() approach.  Flask-SQLAlchemy uses scoped sessions.

Comment: Is there anything in the Postgres logs?